# Azure & Powershell: Get-AzureRmDeletedWebApp throws weird error

Tags: azure, powershell, web-applications

I'm currently testing the cmdlet for restoring erroneously deleted web apps.
To do this I ran the following scripts:

```
."C:\Scripts\Deploy\Prod\Include\include.ps1" #contains the function "get-settings"

$settings=get-Settings # login to Azure account and retrieve system settings as hashtable

Get-AzureRmDeletedWebApp -ResourceGroupName $settings.resourcegroup # call the function with a resource group name
```

Sanity check: Login successful, all settings correct
Resulting errormessage:

> Get-AzureRmDeletedWebApp : String was not recognized as a valid
>   DateTime. At line:3 char:1
>   + Get-AzureRmDeletedWebApp -ResourceGroupName $settings.resourcegroup
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : CloseError: (:) [Get-AzureRmDeletedWebApp], FormatException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.Azure.Commands.WebApps.Cmdlets.WebApps.GetAzureDeletedWebApp

I ran this script on 2 different machines, Win 10 & WinSrv 2012 R2; both throw the same error.
I'm clueless what the cause of the error might be.
Any help appreciated

Thomas

```
PW version:
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
PSVersion                      5.1.14409.1012                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
PSEdition                      Desktop                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}                                                                                                                                                                                                           
BuildVersion                   10.0.14409.1012                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
WSManStackVersion              3.0                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1                                                                                                                                                                                                                           


Version   Name    Repository Description                                                                                                                                                                        
-------   ----    ---------- -----------                                                                                                                                                                        
6.13.1    AzureRM PSGallery  Azure Resource Manager Module
```

Comment: I think it's something wrong in the function get-settings, you can check if it really returns a hashtable. after $settings=get-Settings, you can use $settings.gettype() to see if it's hashtable.

Comment: Thank you., but it doesn't solve the problem. Thatb was one of the first things i checked. This function 'get-settings' is well-tested, I frequently use it and it definitely returns a hashtable.
Even running 'Get-AzureRmDeletedWebApp' w/o parameters throws the same errmsg.

Comment: When a string isn't recognised as a valid date time, its often due to regional settings. E.g the string is laid out in UK date format, but the script expected a US formatted date.

Comment: That's what I generally expect and respect. So the errmsg indeed is true:  the cmdlet 'Get-AzureRmDeletedWebApp" absolutely is not a valid datetime.
As one can read in the docs this function neither expects a datetime as parameter nor returns one.
The question is why it takes the cmdlet name as a datetime?

Comment: Could you specific the `-ResourceGroupName` with a string like `testgroup` directly? What the result if so?

Comment: My guess is that its an internal bug in the cmdlet, as it seemingly returns a "DeletionTime" property and perhaps its trying to use your local regional settings to convert those values to datetime objects in the result, but then they are strings that don't match your regional settings. This is purely a guess, I tried to find the source code for the cmdlet but I think it was written in C#.

Comment: @Joy: Same result with string literal.

Comment: @Mark: Good point. I'll go in this direction and change the locale to en-US.
...when my time permits, sigh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me to be a bug in the way the cmdlet parses dates. If you set your short date format to MM/dd/yy then the cmdlet should execute successfully. You can do this in PowerShell with `Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Control Panel\International" -Name sShortDate -Value MM/dd/yy`. You need to start a new powershell session after you set the date format.

I've raised an issue on GitHub about it https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/8120

Comment: Indeed, it is the registry setting that caused the trouble.

I tinkered with en-us for set-culture and Set-WinSystemLocale, but I never thought of manipulating the reg itself.

Now it works - kind of...:-)

Thanks a lot

Thomas